# Outlook Addin with close the new appointment creation screen

Tags: outlook-addin

I am using c#. I want to close the screen of new appointments with Outlook add-in.

I've tried these codes that are defined below;

```
inspector.Close(Outlook.OlInspectorClose.olDiscard);
inspector.Application.Explorers[0].Close()
```

But it is not working .
[image]

Comment: Inspector.Close is what you want. Are you getting an error?

Comment: does not give an error., form does not close.

Comment: Where does `inspector` variable come from? Have you tried `Application.ActiveInspector`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it as follows. Thank you very much for your interest. @Dmitry Streblechenko

```
void Inspectors_AddNewAppointment(Outlook.Inspector inspector)
    {
        isOpen = false;

        // Get the current item for this Inspecto object and check if is type
        Outlook.AppointmentItem appointmentItem = inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
        if (appointmentItem != null)
        {
            DateTime _start = appointmentItem.Start;

            if (_start.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday || _start.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
            {
                DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(
                    "warring",
                    "warring", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

                if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
                {
                    isOpen = true;
                    //  inspector.Close(Outlook.OlInspectorClose.olDiscard);
                }
            }

            appointmentItem.Open += AppointmentItem_Open;

            
        }
    }

    private void AppointmentItem_Open(ref bool Cancel)
    {
        Cancel = isOpen;
    }
```